# Difference between Javascript "Math.sin" and WebGL"sin"

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, webgl, shader

What is the difference, and how do I get WebGL's sin to produce the same result as Math.sin?

**EDIT:**
I have some code in my vertex shader (this is not all code), that computes a fibonacci point around a sphere and is supposed to place the vertex on this new spot:

```
attribute float index;

   float inc = 3.141592653589793238462643383279 * (3.0 - sqrt(5.0));
   float off = 2.0 / 2500000;
   float yy = index * off - 1.0 + (off / 2.0);
   float rr = sqrt(1.0 - yy * yy);
   float phi = index* inc;
   vec3 fibPoint = vec3(cos(phi) * rr, yy, sin(phi) * rr);
```

This doesn't work, it gives me awkward vertex locations like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zm5qg.png

If I instead compute cos(phi) and sin(phi) on the CPU with javascript's Math.sin and Math.cos and throw them in as an attribute, like this:

```
attribute float index;
attribute float sinphi;
attribute float cosphi;

   float inc = 3.141592653589793238462643383279 * (3.0 - sqrt(5.0));
   float off = 2.0 / 2500000;
   float yy = index * off - 1.0 + (off / 2.0);
   float rr = sqrt(1.0 - yy * yy);
   float phi = index* inc;
   vec3 fibPoint = vec3(cosphi * rr, yy, sinphi * rr);
```

I get a fine fibonacci distribution like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QaWC.png

Any ideas on why, obviously it seems like there is some difference in the cos/sin functions between GLSL and Javascript? Phi can become quite large numbers, like "5476389.695241543" kind of large. Maybe that is too big for GLSL's precision?

**EDIT 2:**

```
vertexShader: [
    "attribute float index;",
    "attribute float cosphi;",
    "attribute float sinphi;",
    "attribute float displacementType;",
    "uniform vec3 faceCorner;",
    "uniform vec3 faceNormal;",
    "uniform vec3 faceCenter;",
    "varying vec2 vTexCoord;",

    "void main()",
    "{",

          "vTexCoord = uv;",

          // find fibonacci distribution of points on sphere
          "float inc = 3.141592653589793238462643383279 * 0.7639320225002102;",
          "float off = 0.0000008;",

          "float yy = index* off - 1.0 + (off / 2.0);",
          "float rr = sqrt(1.0 - yy * yy);",
          "float phi = index* inc;",
          "vec3 fibPoint = vec3(cos(phi) * rr * -1.0, yy, sin(phi) * rr * -1.0);",

          // intersecting face
          "vec3 normalizedFaceNormal = normalize(faceNormal);",
          "float planeConstant = - dot(faceCorner, normalizedFaceNormal);", 
          "float denominator = dot(normalizedFaceNormal, fibPoint);",
          "float distanceToPlane = - planeConstant / denominator;",

          "vec3 intersectPoint = normalize(fibPoint) * distanceToPlane;",
          "intersectPoint = faceCenter;",

          // displacement
          "float buildingRadius = 3.0;",                
          "vec3 newPosition = position;",
          "vec3 cornerVec = normalize(faceCorner - intersectPoint) * buildingRadius;",

            // ground vertices
           "if(displacementType == 0.0){",
                "newPosition = intersectPoint + cornerVec;",
           "} else if(displacementType == 1.0){",
                "newPosition = cross(cornerVec, normalizedFaceNormal);",    
                "newPosition = intersectPoint + newPosition;",
            "} else if(displacementType == 2.0){",
                "newPosition = intersectPoint - cornerVec;",
           "} else if(displacementType == 3.0){",
                "newPosition = cross(normalizedFaceNormal, cornerVec);",    
                "newPosition = intersectPoint + newPosition;",

           "} else {",
                  // roof vertices
               "vec3 corner0 = intersectPoint + cornerVec;",
               "vec3 corner1 = intersectPoint + cross(cornerVec, normalizedFaceNormal);",

                "float UVdistance = length(corner0 - corner1);",
                "float buildingHeight = UVdistance * 2.0;",

                "vec3 roofCentroid = intersectPoint + normalizedFaceNormal * (-buildingHeight);",

                "if(displacementType == 4.0){",
                    "newPosition = roofCentroid + cornerVec;",
                "} else if(displacementType == 5.0){",
                    "newPosition = cross(cornerVec, normalizedFaceNormal);",
                    "newPosition = roofCentroid + newPosition;",
                "} else if(displacementType == 6.0){",
                    "newPosition = roofCentroid - cornerVec;",
                "} else {",
                    "newPosition = cross(normalizedFaceNormal, cornerVec);",    
                    "newPosition = roofCentroid + newPosition;",
                "}",
            "}",

            "gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(newPosition.xyz, 1.0);",
    "}"
].join("\n"),
```

So this one gives the faulty vertex positions, if I change "cos(phi)" and "sin(phi)" to cosphi and sinphi, which are the attributes, calculated on the CPU, by javascript's Math.sin(phi) and Math.cos(phi), then the code works. The buildings/cubes are intact, so the displacement works and the intersecting works since the buildings/cubes get put at the surface of the sphere, with correct distanceToPlane.

**ANSWER by Cornstalks on gamedev.net:**

> The big number is an issue. If your vertex shader is working with
>   32-bit floats, that only gives you 6 decimal digits of precision.
>   5476389.695241543 to 6 decimal digits of precision is 5476380.000000 (truncating everything after the 6 digits). Pi is only ~3.14, and
>   since sin/cos are periodic, using large numbers doesn't give you any
>   benefit over using smaller numbers (because the large numbers just
>   wrap around). However, your numbers are so large that they wrap around
>   so much that they don't even precisely map to the [-pi, pi] (or [0,
>   2pi]) range. Basically, the wrapping around throws away all the "high"
>   digits and only keeps the relevant low digits, but unfortunately for
>   you all your low digits are junk because you spent all 6 of your
>   precision digits on the ones that get thrown away, and now all your
>   low (but most important) digits are meaningless.
>
> In short, yes, those huge numbers will kill you.
>
> However, in JavaScript, all floating point numbers are 64-bit, which
>   gives you 15 decimal digits of precision. That means in JavaScript you
>   can actually properly represent 5476389.69524154, so your trig
>   calculations are actually accurate (assuming your JavaScript code is
>   processing the same large values that your vertex shader is).

Comment: For interest, here's the whole thread over on gamedev.net: http://www.gamedev.net/topic/645229-javascripts-%E2%80%9Cmathsinmathcos%E2%80%9D-and-webgls-%E2%80%9Csincos%E2%80%9D-give-different-results/